# What is the best way to analyse/debug the events fired in java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm a beginner in java and swing applications. Sometimes, some action events are fired multiple times( like `key listener, action listener`, because we make many changes in the same class many times. One day, we find it is calling multiple times.  It is very difficult for me to find where they are triggered.
All these `action performed` and events for `Mouse & keyboard` are coming for in-build java classes.
So, it is hard to find the exact code which is causing the issue.We don't know where to look.

So, what is the best way to debug them and find the exact place in the code?

Comment: There is no best way.  You can use an IDE debugger or add lots of System.out.println statements.  One good way is to always use a [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  By separating the parts of your Swing application, it's easier to isolate the code with the problem.

Comment: My Bad!!!. Thanks, mate